# Does an upgrade to Windows 10 preserve registry settings

Tags: windows, java, windows-10-upgrade

Our software is relying on Java's built in presistent Preferences, which stores all settings in the registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs

Should these registry keys be preserved when a user upgrades from Windows 7 to Windows 10?

Or is it to be expected that these keys will disappear and local preferences will be lost?

Comment: Depends what upgrade option you choose. "Preserve programs and settings" preserves programs and settings (including registry entries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did on my machine. (And, yes, you must use the "Preserve programs and settings" option.)